# Is there any mythological/scriptural reference linking Periyachi with Narasimha

Tags: identification-request, goddess

I recently came across the deity [Periyachi Amman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periyachi) (See pic).
The iconography is very reminiscent of [Narasimha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narasimha) (see other pic), though the story is rather different. However, the net import of the story also seemed to be a deity protecting a child even to the extent of harming the parents. 
Is there any scriptural or mythological reference linking these two deities?

[image: Periyachi Amman]
[image: Narasimha]